# Problem with zooming out (and staying zoomed out) in a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

In my app, I'm using a UIWebView to view email contents.  I'm setting its `frame` to the size of the screen, and the contents are usually much larger than the screen size so I have to scroll up/down and left/right to view the entire contents.

I want to be able to zoom out by pinching the contents - which of course makes everything smaller - so that I can see the entire email on the screen at once.  This is currently working, but the problem is that as soon as I lift my fingers off the screen, the contents "snap" back to their normal size.

How can I pinch-zoom a UIWebView so that it stays zoomed?

Comment: @Joe: about damn time you tried to help me! :) As far as I know (I'm trying to modify somebody else's code), there is no pinch-handling logic anywhere. I think we're just relying on the built-in UIWebView behavior.

Comment: DAMMIT JOE!!!! HOW AM I SUPPOSED TO WRITE AMAZING MUSIC SOFTWARE WHEN I CAN'T EVEN ZOOM OUT ON AN EMAIL???

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the [viewport](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/usingtheviewport/usingtheviewport.html) tag in the HTML content of the webview.

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

Comment: This does not solve the problem - the webview continues to snap back